# Laptop doesn't start after being shutdown for a couple of hours except when connected to power

Tags: windows-10, laptop, power-supply, battery

I'm using an HP Compaq 6530b laptop and for a year or more now, my laptop doesn't start after it has been shut down, hibernated, or even after removing the battery for a few hours, and only happens when my laptop has been off for ~2hrs or more:

- Anytime I try to turn it on, the power LED comes on and the charging led blinks for a few seconds before they both turn off; the only way I can turn on the laptop is to connect it to power, let it charge for a minute, disconnect the charger, click the power button, and connect the charger as the led light is blinking
- My battery is not dead because when it comes on, the percentage is around where I left it and it's not damaged, as I recently changed it and it still behaves like that

The only way I'm able to avoid this is to put the laptop to sleep and make sure it doesn't enter hibernation.

- You may think it's not a problem because it comes on when I connect to AC, but I live in a third world country and we don't have power as much, so if I need to do something important, I'll have to wait till the power comes back on

Comment: It's failing POST - refer to your PC's manual for what the number of power lights blinks indicates.

Answer (score 0):

In case this is not a problem of the battery, here are some more checks
that you may do.

- Run `chkdsk` to check for disk corruption
- Check the SMART data of the disk (for example using
  [Speccy](https://www.ccleaner.com/speccy))
- Run
  [SFC and DISM](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html):

  ```
    DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth
    sfc /scannow
  ```
- If nothing is found do
  [Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html).